# Addressing header of csv without knowing their names

Tags: powershell, csv, properties

I have to import a .csv file with powershell that have not always the same amount of columns. How can i adress the name of the header if there names are not every import the same but are on the same position?

Lets say the header names would be A, B, C, D,... and so on. Then the code snippet would look like:

```
| ForEach-Object { if ($_.M -gt $_.N) {$_.K = 'Y'} if ($_.M -le $_.N) {$_.K = 'N'} $_} |
```

Is there any possibility in Powershell to adress the header without knowing the name, only the number of the position?

Regards, Alex

Comment: You can access the `.PSObject.Properties` of the first object to know what columns your Csv has

Comment: Was too quick. Sorry. @SantiagoSquarzon thank you very much for your help. I have now the names. With the following code. 
$headers = import-csv stock.csv 
$headers[0].PSObject.Properties.Name
When i have that piped csv in the code above? If i understand it right i need in case of header M the 13th row of the column name. 
I could not find it. Regards, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, you can use the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views) for reflecting on the properties of any object, including the `[pscustomobject]` instances that [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) emit.

This allows you to:

- obtain an array of property (CSV column) names based on the first parsed object...
- ... into which you can *index* and use the resulting string as the property name in a [member-access operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) (`.`), which allows specifying *expressions* (i.e. non-static values) as property names.

In the following example, the values of the third column (whose `0`-based index is `2`) are extracted, without having to know the name of the column:

```bash
# Create a sample CSV file
@'
"Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"
"1a","1b","1c","1d"
"2a","2b","2c","2d"
'@ > test.csv

$colNames = $null # Initialize the variable that will store the column names.

Import-Csv test.csv |
  ForEach-Object {

    # Unless previously obtained, get the array of property (CSV column) names.
    if ($null -eq $colNames) { $colNames = $_.psobject.Properties.Name }    

    # Access the 3rd column (property) by index (2).
    # Note the use of expression $colNames[2] as the property name,
    # enclosed in (...)
    "Third column value: " + $_.($colNames[2])
  }
```

Output:

```
Third column value: 1c
Third column value: 2c
```

---

Note: If you want to **determine the column names by index *ahead of time***, in a separate step, e.g. in case you won't be using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) later to process the objects, use the following:

```bash
# Get the first row (only) and extract its property names,
# which reflect the CSV column names.
[array] $colNames = 
  (Import-Csv test.csv | Select-Object -First 1).psobject.Properties.Name

# Get the name of the first and third columns, for instance.
$firstcolName = $colNames[0]
$thirdcolName = $colNames[2]

# Now read the whole file and extract the columns of interest, 
# using Select-Object in this example.
Import-Csv test.csv | Select-Object $firstcolName, $thirdcolName
```

Output:

```bash
Col1 Col3
---- ----
1a   1c
2a   2c
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I think i understand it now how it works. Will try it later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mklement0. Based on his idea i got the idea to the solution. For all who might come later and find the solution helpfull.

```
`$inFilePath = 'data.csv'
    $csvColumnHeader = (Get-Content $inFilePath  | Select-Object -First 1 ).Split(";").replace('"','')
    $headercolumn4 = $csvColumnHeader[3]
    $headercolumn5 = $csvColumnHeader[4]
    $headercolumn8 = $csvColumnHeader[7]`
```

Then you can use the variables to adress the name of the header.

Regards, Alex

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but this is one is inferior to the one shown in my answer, with incidental variations: there is no need for the extra step of performing _plain-text_ parsing of the input file's first line. In other words: what you're showing will not benefit future readers.

Comment: Specifically, if you want to determine the column names ahead of time, the robust and simpler solution is to use `$csvColumnHeader = (Import-Csv $inFilePath | Select-Object -First 1).psobject.Properties.Name` - I've updated my answer to show this solution.

Comment: @mklement0 i know understand it. Sorry, im not that good in Powershell and are learning it at the moment. Thank you very much for your help and explanation. Regards, Alex

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Alex; my pleasure. In hindsight I see that the original form of my answer wasn't detailed enough.